number of distinct roots of random polynomial
Let $P$ be a uniformly random polynomial over a finite field $\mathbf{F}_p$ of degree $n$.
What can we say about the number of distinct roots of $P$ (in the algebraic closure of $\mathbf{F}_p$)?
I am particularly interested in the large $n$ limit. Does $P$ have, with high probability as $n$ tends to infinity, many distinct roots?

A recent related thread.

The probability that an element $\alpha \in \bar{\mathbf F_p}$ of degree $d \leq n$ is a root of a uniformly randomly chosen polynomial is $p^{-d}$. There are $\phi(p^d-1)$ elements of degree, plus zero, which is of degree $1$. The expected number of distinct roots should be $\frac 1p + \sum_{d=1}^n p^{-d}\phi(p^d - 1)$. Doesn't look like this expression simplifies,  but maybe someone sees something for $n \to \infty$.

@Tzimmo Your approach is probably useful for saying something about the question. But the number of elements with a minimal polynomial of degree $d$ is
$$N_d=\sum_{m\mid d}p^{d/m}\mu(m),$$ where $\mu$ is the Möbius function. Those are the elements $\alpha$ that generate the field $\bf{F}_{p^d}=\bf{F}_p(\alpha)$. But they don't need to generate its multiplicative group, which is something you may have had in mind.

@JyrkiLahtonen Yes, I mixed those up. Thanks for correcting me.
